# How to EXCLUDE "winsock2.h"?

Tags: c

I am doing a project on Windows and the "winsock2.h" file is causing issues during compilation (I have an underlying queue library that has function like "send", "receive" etc and it is complaining about the "winsock2.h" also having a "send" function).

I am just including "windows.h", so is there a way I can **EXCLUDE** the inclusion of "winsock2.h" so that my application can compile?

Thanks for the help ;-)

Lynton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before including windows.h, you get a lot fewer headers automatically pulled in.

Though on my system, windows.h includes winsock.h, not winsock2.h, so you may have to double-check it's actually due to including windows.h.

Comment: This one seems better, the #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN seems to have gotten rid of that winsock2.h stuff....getting some other errors though, let me dig into it,.....thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, winsock2.h contains an inclusion guard `#ifndef _WINSOCK2API_` so defining `_WINSOCK2API_` before you include windows.h should prevent it from being included.

Though a better solution, IMO, is to put your library in it's own namespace (e.g. queue_send, msgq_send, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried to define _WINSOCK2API_ before the header file and it still gave the same error. I don't really want to change the namespace of my external library as it is happy on Unix etc and I don't feel like I have to bow down to Windows at all. But thanks for your comments, I appreciate it ;-)

Comment: @Lynton: Looks like you forgot the underscores.

Comment: By the way, on unix your program has undefined behavior if it redefines the function `send` (which is defined by POSIX), unless your definition is `static`.